# DICOM MRI images resolution

Tags: mri, angular-spatial-resoluton, dicom

I've received a CD with the results of my MRI. The images seem very grainy and the maximum resolution of the images is around 320x320px or 512x512px.

Is this typical for these kind of images? It's hard for me to see any detail with such a low resolution. I'm sure when the doctor showed me the images on his computer screen there were much more detail.

Comment: That sounds very odd to me. I might be wrong of course since my relationship with DICOM is a passing-one at best (I'm a GP), but it is my understanding DICOM images are actually vector-based and thus do not have a limit on resolution by themselves. It might be that your CD has rasterized versions of the images, or might be that the software that is bundled on the CD along with the images is a crappy shareware viewer, as is more-commonly-than-I'd-like the case.

Comment: Thanks, the biggest files I could find on the CD was not very large (325KB) which was rendered to a 384x384 bitmap image. So it does seem like there might be some extra information in that file. I'll try some other applications. Maybe it's like you said, the software probably does a poor job of displaying the images.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. It is common for CT and MR images to have a number of rows and columns equal to either 320 or 512.

I suggest you to download the [MicroDicom DICOM Viewer](https://www.microdicom.com/downloads.html) to load and view your MR images. On the right hand corner of the user interface you will find a column which lists all the tags associated to the images. Among them, the `(0028, 0030) Pixel Spacing`attribute gives you the distance between the center of each pixel.